# titanium mobile: merge two array into one array issue

Tags: android, titanium-mobile

Hello friends,

I have developing an app in Titanium and I have an issue is that merge two array into one array so please give me idea to my issue.

Thanks in advance.

```
var tableData = ['Restaurants','Coffee','Bars','ATMs','Gas Stations','Hotels','Attractions','Pizza','Post Office'];

var categoryData = [];

var tableData = [];

PlacesTypeCells = function createRow() 
{   


    alert('custom cells'+currentWindow.category);
    if(currentWindow.category)
    {
        alert('add category');
        categoryData.push(currentWindow.category);
    }

    tableData = placeData + categoryData;
    Ti.API.log('length:'+tableData);
    alert(tableData.length);
}
```

**I want merge placeData and categoryData into tableData array so please give me idea how can I do this?**

Comment: placeData is not defined in your code. Please correct it. And to merge two arrays use : javascript concat method.

Answer (score 2):

```
tableData = categoryData.concat(placeData);
```

try this